# How to navigate to other parts of partial methods?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is there a way to navigate to other parts of a partial method (or class)?

I'm looking for something like F12.

Comment: what is that you exactly want ? please clarify yourself.

Comment: Do you mean execute "Find all references" from VS?

Comment: @Tigran:yea something like find all references but gets me a list of definitions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it not appear in the drop down list of functions at the top of the editor?  The function will appear twice the paler version is the one in another file.